# Marklogic : How to use resources

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

I have created resources for `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` using REST convention. I want to use it.

Please let me know, how to use the resource which I have created.

Comment: Post the command you used to initialize the resource extension.

Comment: I have registered the sjs file using following command - curl --anyauth --user userName:password -X PUT -i -H "Content-type: application/vnd.marklogic-javascript" --data-binary @./getExample.sjs 'http://localhost:8500/LATEST/config/resources/get-example'

Comment: Resource extensions are installed at `http://host:port/version/resources/extensionName`, so yours should be accessible at `http://localhost:8500/LATEST/resources/get-example`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by using the resource while querying the database.  The resources are separate calls, as documented at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_13882.  What exactly do you want to do?  What is in your GET resource, for example?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created resource and added http headers . I wanted to use the created resource while searching the element.  I have created one transform function instead that did the job for me.